# Android get EditText value in a dialog [empty string returned]

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-dialog

I have a dialog Fragment containing an EditText, from which i want to retrieve the value, but when i try, i get an empty String.
Here is my Dialog code

```
public class PersonEditDialog extends DoubleActionDialog{



public PersonEditDialog() {

}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_personne_edit, null))
    .setPositiveButton(R.string.s_button_save, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            doAction();
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton(R.string.s_button_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            PersonEditDialog.this.getDialog().cancel();
        }
    });   
    builder.setTitle(getTitleId());
    return builder.create();
}

@Override
public void doUpdate() {
    // mise à jour de la personne
    View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_personne_edit, null);
    EditText nom = (EditText)  view.findViewById(R.id.nom);
    EditText prenom = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.prenom);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), nom.getText() + " " + prenom.getText() + " mis à jour", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void doCreate() {
    // ajout de la personne
    View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_personne_edit, null);
    EditText nom = (EditText)  view.findViewById(R.id.nom);
    EditText prenom = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.prenom);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), nom.getText().toString() + " " + prenom.getText().toString() + " créé", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
protected int getUpdateLabelId() {
    return R.string.s_title_edit_person;
}

@Override
protected int getCreateLabelId() {
    return R.string.s_title_add_person;
}
```

}

the doAction() method invokes one of the two methods : doUpdate() or doCreate() depending on the value of a parameter.

The doCreate() or doUpdate() are trying to read the content o the EditText.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are inflating a new layout and getting the contents of the edittexts in this new layout. Since the layout where the edittexts are is the dialog layout, you can use `getDialog()` in a `DialogFragment` to get a reference to the dialog and call `findViewById()` on it.

For example, replace the

```
View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_personne_edit, null);
```

with something like

```
Dialog dlg = getDialog();
```

and then call `dlg.findViewById(...)`.

Comment: I did this, but the returned view is null :/

Comment: I used the getDialog() as you suggested, and it worked. thanks. Still, have a question, what's the onCreateView() which i didn't override is supposed to return ?

Comment: It provides the fragment view hierarchy in a regular fragment. You have a dialog fragment. I was thinking of regular fragments first and only then read enough of the code to see it's probably a dialogfragment.

Comment: I have been searching for the reason of empty String returns for several hours and finally found this was the actual reason. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an empty `String` because you are trying to get it from a different `EditText`. In your `doUpdate` and `doCreate` methods you are creating new `View`s with the layout  `activity_personne_edit`.

Instead in `onCreateDialog` you should inflate the layout into a global `View` object like

```
layoutView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_personne_edit, null);
builder.setView(layoutView)
```

and then in your `doUpdate` and `doCreate` methods change

```
EditText nom = (EditText)  layoutView.findViewById(R.id.nom);
EditText prenom = (EditText) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.prenom);
```

to

```
EditText nom = (EditText)  layoutView.findViewById(R.id.nom);
EditText prenom = (EditText) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.prenom);
```

and no need to create the `view` object then.